# Any stock means of inserting a period by pressing the spacebar twice?

Tags: macos

I've grown to really appreciate the ability to press space twice on my iOS devices and have a period manually inserted without having to switch keyboards.

Though I realize the need isn't quite there on actual keyboards since the key is accessible at all times, I'm curious: **Is there any way to get the same behavior using baked-in functionality on Mac OS X?**

This is assuming the most recent version of Mountain Lion is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Language & Text / Text**
2. Add a new rule where **"  "** (double space) is replaced with **". "** (period space).
3. Make sure you've got *Symbol and Text Substitution* enabled, and this new *rule* checked, too.

It appears not to work *everywhere*, though.

Comment: Sweet, I'll check it out when I get home and accept this guy if it works out. Either way, thank you for the answer!

Comment: This doesn't work in OS X 10.9.4. The original text cannot contain spaces: http://link.olivierlacan.com/image/0A1L3k1N2I1p. It's too bad, really.